# Converting an array in curly braces to a square bracketed array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I've inherited a database that stores an array of strings in the following format:

```
{"First","Second","Third","Fourth"}
```

This is output as an ordered list in the application. We're replacing the front-end mobile app at the moment (ionic / angular) and want to do an ngFor over this array. In the first iteration, we did a quick and dirty replace on the curly brackets and then split the string on "," but would like to use a better method.

What is the best method for treating this type of string as an array?

Comment: Better how? What's wrong with the method you are using?

Comment: Just replace first and last squiggly with a bracket and `JSON.parse` the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do a string replacement of braces to brackets:

```
str.replace(/{(.*)}/, '[$1]')
```

This particular string could then be parsed as an array (via JSON.parse).

Comment: Yes - this is almost exactly what we have in place but followed by a split. I'll leave this open for a little while but I suppose we might just swap that to JSON.parse and leave it there. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to do the parsing to an array on the front end, would this work?:

```js
const oldStyle = '{"First","Second","Third","Fourth"}'

const parseOldStyleToArray = input => input
  .replace(/[\{\}]/g, '')
  .split(',')
  .map(item => item.replace(/\"/g, ''))
  

const result = parseOldStyleToArray(oldStyle)

console.dir(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do more widest replacement by `key:value` mapping.

```js
str = '{"First","Second","Third","Fourth"}';
mapping = {
  '{': '[',
  '}': ']'
}
result = str.replace(/[{}]/g, m => mapping[m]);
console.log(result);
```